# How to call a PageReference from a Constructor

Tags: apex, controller, visualforce, pagereference

I have this following apex:

```
public class SampleController {

    public SampleController(){

        //I want to call the the samplepage() here.

    }

    public PageReference samplepage(){

        PageReference pagr= new PageReference('/apex/sample?id='+sampleID);          
        pagr.setRedirect(false);  
        return pagr;

    }

}
```

How to call the page reference from constructor?..
Or any idea that I can direct call a vf page from the contsructor?..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't return a PageReference from a constructor, but you can use an action method when the page loads:

```
<apex:page controller="SampleController" action="{!samplepage}" ...
```

This will have the effect of redirecting on page load.